# Running Functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am trying to run some functions in Visual Studio Code, but it doesn't work and a window keeps opening saying Cannot find runtime node on PATH. 
Here are the codes:

```
function multiply(num1,num2) {let result = num1 * num2; return result;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easy way to do this would be to uninstall node, and reinstall it, **making sure to check "Add to PATH"** is in your Setup:

[image]

Then afterwards you might need to kill the terminal and pull up a new one for the install to take place.